# Cannot create a new return policy in eBay sandbox

Tags: ebay-api

https://www.bizpolicy.sandbox.ebay.com/businesspolicy/return?pageNumber=1&totalPages=1&source=manage

says

```
Please provide the correct information in the highlighted fields

    We're having a problem right now. Please try again later.
```

What do I do incorrectly?

[image: create return policy]

Comment: Delete number and try again.

Comment: It's kinda looking server-side error.

Comment: ok I will try later

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: You can contact with customer service